# ionic framework and firebase (one on one chat with authenticated user)

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase

I have a code that registers a user in ionic,  using firebase email/password auth. but what I want to do is that I want to list all user from my  user node and begin to chat with them
 (without making anyone to join chat room)...
or if there is a way to list all user base of geo-location.

My system battery is dead and I am only posting from my android device, I would have posted my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have object structure in firebase like so:

```
{
    users: {
         user1: {...}
         user2: {...}
         user3: {...}
    }
}
```

The easiest way to would be store all the users into a `$firebaseArray` and then use `ng-repeat` to list them onto the page as such:

ANGULAR:

```
var usersRef = new Firebase('https://samplechat.firebaseio-demo.com/users');

// Make sure `$firebaseArray` is injeted into your controller
// I assume you know how to use Angular since you are using Ionic

$scope.users = $firebaseArray(usersRef);
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Template must be connected to controller -->
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item" ng-repeat="user in users"> user.$id </li>
</ul>
```

[$firebaseArray](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-arrays.html)

[Ionic Lists](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#list)

To order your users by geo-location you would have to store that geo-location as an object property of the user and then query them accordingly using
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/

Your firebase reference would be changed, but the following steps would the same.

Comment: Yep, ask if you have any issues.

Comment: thank u... ur answer nailed it but i have issue with implementing the firechat with the user i just itemize  from my firebase

Comment: Explain a little more.